# Deleting duplicated features with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, cursor, delete

I try to use this python code in order to delete duplicated feature which as the same xy coordinate of centroid (i created those fields with Calculated Geometry in the attribute table):

```
import arcpy
'''
first we create x center coordinate field (the same for y) in the attribute
table manually, then we will run this code.
'''
list1 = []
listToDeleteX = []
listToDeleteY = []
fc = r"G:\desktop\Project\lyr\polygon.shp"
# check the x coordinate
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, "xCenter") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        list1.append(row)
        if list1.count(row)>1:
            listToDeleteX.append(row)

 # check the y coordinate
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, "yCenter") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        list1.append(row)
        if list1.count(row)>1:
            listToDeleteY.append(row)

listToDeleteY.append(listToDeleteX)
```

in the end of the code i added the x list to the y list but i don't know how to delete the duplicated rows.

I work with arcGIS for Desktop so i don't have any extensions and i can't use the "arcpy.DeleteIdentical_management" tool.

This is the attribute table of the polygon layer:

[image]

Comment: It is much easier done with the dictionary. Start populating it with first cursor using xy tuple as a key and fid a s value. If key not in dictionary, add it, otherwise populate list of fids to delete. Use select query fid in () and delete features tool to accomplish the task

Comment: how to do it with a dictionary?

Comment: Rather than use a dictionary why not use a `Set`? When you add to a set, if the value exists already then it's dropped, so you build up a unique list of values.

Comment: how to integrated it in my code?

Comment: I found Sets are good for creating unique number lists but in hind sight I think @FelixIP idea of using a dictionary is a better way to go as then you need only traverse the table once.

Comment: Using an UpdateCursor without doing any update is wasteful -- This is a job for a DA SearchCursor.  Your code fails to record the FID of the shapefile row (zero-based row index), and the comparison logic would try to delete every row after the first one (fortunately, no attempt is made to delete a row).  Using a centroid would be a questionable technique anyway, since comparison on floating-point values might not match due to  representation issues.  What you really want is a comparison on duplicate T_ID.

Comment: no Vince, i want to insure there no duplicated xy centroid coordinates. the T_ID is just string with no importance to me.

Answer (score 4):

This code will work on a table and searches a numeric field called test to find and delete duplicates. It assumes the first instance of a duplicate value is the one you want to keep.

```py
import arcpy

def main():
    dict = {} # dictionary, key is test value, item is objectID
    tbl = r"C:\Scratch\fGDB_AIS_Cleaned.gdb\test" # Table to test

    # Search table adding only the first occurance of a value and it's objectID
    print "reading dataset..."
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(tbl,["OBJECTID","test"]) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            objID = row[0]
            val = row[1]
            if dict.has_key(val) == False:
                dict[val] = objID

    # Get a list of objectIDs to keep
    oList = dict.values()

    # Check duplicates if they exist
    n = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(tbl).getOutput(0))
    if n > len(oList):
        print "deleting duplicates..."
        # create a sql expression on ObjectID
        sql = "OBJECTID NOT IN (" + str(oList) + ")"
        sql = sql.replace("[","")
        sql = sql.replace("]","")

        # Delete duplicates
        arcpy.MakeTableView_management(tbl,"tocleanup")
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("tocleanup","NEW_SELECTION",sql)
        arcpy.DeleteRows_management("tocleanup")
        print "deleted duplicate rows!"
        arcpy.Delete_management("tocleanup")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    print "finished!"
```

One thing to consider, I have found deleting from very large datasets (e.g. millions of rows) can be *very* slow. It is much quicker to copy out rows you want to keep into a new dataset.

Comment: i don't understand where to insert the key\ value of the dictionary?

Comment: The insertion is this line: dict[val] = objID. Unlike VB which would have been something like myDict.Add(val,objID) you simply assign it to insert it.

Comment: sorry but i don't understand: i want to use the xCenter and the yCenter fields as the key\value- where i insert them?

Comment: Either use the T_ID field as @Vince suggested or you concatenate the fields into a single value, so convert them into text with str() and combine them into a single long string, this would give your unique value.

Comment: +1 str(tuple(oList)) will make it shorter

Comment: @FelixIP, ah! Thats how you turn a list into comma separated numbers in brackets, nice! :)

Comment: @Hornbydd, don't forget  yourTuple+=(-1,) because this thing fails with single entry